# External Link not working in CSS & HMTL because of zero size

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I have a pretty simple issue that there I have social class and then facebook. In facebook class I am attacking facebook icon as background in normal and hover.

```
<div class="social socialteam facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
</div>
```

These classes have nothing special which can block the link
CSS Code

```
.social { display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; width: 32px; height: 32px; margin-right: 5px; }
.facebook { background: url(../images/facebook.png) }
.facebook:hover { background: url(../images/facebooka.png) }
```

After analyzing inspect element and checking layout and computed tabs, i realized that the size of
`<a href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>` is 0 (zero)
So if i place space ( &amp ; ) it works but then it loses its regular place and shows one line below.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">&nbsp;</a>
```

So what is there any workaround that i can make the link work without its place getting changed?

With correct placement but link not working [image]

With incorrect placement but link working [image]

Thank You

Comment: The div is showing with the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link has nothing in it so it has no dimensions (links are inline elements so unless there's something in it, it will take no space) - you either need to add the social class to the link or add another class and give it some dimensions so it fills the div

Below I have added a social-link class to the link and then styled it so that it fills the parent div:

```css
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* this is what is added to make the link fill the parent */
.social-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.facebook {
  background: red url(../images/facebook.png)
}

.facebook:hover {
  background: blue url(../images/facebooka.png)
}
```

```html
<div class="social socialteam facebook">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="social-link"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When the size of background image is Larger than the Element, we could use CSS to adjust the Background image to fit the element:

```css
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.facebook {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200);

  /*Using these attributes*/
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="social socialteam facebook">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_tamil/dwpqy138/18/